# R lm() weights argument being ignored when placed inside function

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to figure out why the following piece of code ignores the weights argument and produces simply an unweighted regression analysis. If I remove the function wrapping everything works fine. The only way the code runs is if I change  the code so that **weights=richiu**, but I really don't know why the original code would not work in a function environment. Any clear explanations would be really helpful.

```
set.seed(1)
UU=rnorm(1000)
ZZ=rnorm(UU)
futa=data.frame(UU,ZZ)
stringy=paste("ZZ~UU",sep="")
friga=function(stringy,futa){
  richiu=rnorm(1000)
  futa$richiu=richiu
  print(colnames(futa))
  lm(stringy,data=futa, weights=futa$richiu)
}
friga(stringy,futa=futa)
lm(ZZ~UU)
```

Comment: I think `richiu` is interpreted as `futa$richiu` automatically so just `weights=richiu` will do it. From `?lm` help file - "*All of 'weights', 'subset' and 'offset' are evaluated in the same
     way as variables in 'formula', that is first in 'data' and then in
     the environment of 'formula'.*"

Comment: which package are you taking `rdirichlet` from? This would be easier to reproduce if we knew (or if you wrote the example to avoid using it - I doubt this is a necessary component of the example ...)

Comment: sorry there I have changed it to be normal instead of dirichlet.